# Is a buffer stage needed in this signal chain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, signal, buffer

I am designing a signal chain that includes a 4 pole cascade Sallen-Key filter based on the AD8034. The circuit will be used to shape tail pulses (~10ns rise time, ~50us decay) into gaussians. The filter design is taken directly from [page 20 of the AD8034 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8033_8034.pdf). I would like to include two [AD8009](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8009.pdf) gain stages before the filter as shown in the schematic below. Is a buffer stage separating the AD8009 from the AD8034 necessary in this case?

[image: schematic]

Comment: I don't see why you would need one? Pin 3 of U7A draws no current, so what is the buffer for?

Comment: Some of your resistor values are very low. My rough rule: If an opamp is driving less than 1k impedance, I make sure that the opamp can drive the output to the expected voltage.

Comment: @Mattman944 Are refering to the feedback resistors on the AD8009s? I got these values from the datasheet for G = +10 (page 2 of datasheet).

Comment: The AD8009 is OK, it is a video amp, much more powerful than a normal opamp. The AD8034 is more of a normal opamp and it has 100 ohm loads that I don't see any reason for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a buffer stage is to prevent the current drawn by the next stage from affecting the voltage output of the previous stage, i.e. to bridge a high-impedance output to a low-impedance input.

The inputs of U7 AD8034 have *very* high impedance - at least at DC. For AC, I guess working it out would require some complex calculations I'm not familiar with. The input capacitance as specified as "a few pF". Adding a buffer stage would have the same capacitance in the buffer stage so it wouldn't improve anything, anyway.

In fact, if you look at how the circuit is constructed, U7A **is** a buffer stage!